# Vertical space between ul and p in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with class with style as below.

```
.testclass{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px #efefef solid;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 25px;
    padding:25px 20px 20px;
}
.testclass p{
    font-size:12px;
    color:#666;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 20px;
 }
.testclass ul{
    list-style:outside;
    list-style-image:url(/images/img/bullet.png);
    margin:0 0 0 20px;
    padding:0 0 20px;
}
.testclass li{
    font-size:12px;
    color:#666!important;
    padding:0 0 10px;
}

<div class="testclass" style="padding-top:5px">
    <p>blah blah</p>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
    </ul>
```

I have a page in which the div container, has paragraph and ul. I am having a vertical space between the ul and the paragraph. 
How do I get rid of the vertical space. Attached is an image.

[image]

Comment: Well, you have padding on the paragraph, that's why. We cannot see the image maybe I am missing something

Comment: I re-added the image. I tried making padding:0 0 0 still didnt work.

Comment: Would you mind providing a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d3WZ3/ Here is the Fiddle, Here It is displaying correctly, but in my page the bottom paragraph is displaying verticl to the list items.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
.testclass li{
  font-size:12px;
  color:#666!important;
  padding:0 0 20px;
  margin-top: -10px
}
```

You can change the margin-top value to obtain the result you want.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n5Yq/)

Did this help?

Comment: I try not to downvote, but this is a band-aid solution instead of addressing the actual cause.

Comment: @joshboley, I'm sorry you didn't like it. I was just trying to help and offered a possible solution. The visual result may be what the asker wants and, if it isn't, he's just free to not use it. I'll upvote your answer because I think the result is the same he wants

Answer (score 1):

You have bottom padding on your p element:

```
.testclass p{font-size:12px;color:#666;margin:0;padding:0 0 **20px**;}
```

Just set it to 0.  Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/95Txg/)